# Better idea than triple nested switch?

Tags: php, forms, nested, switch-statement

Hi I've got some form for uploading files through php script, where user pick a one category, than second sub-category and then type of file.

I have to upload it on server into correct directory and path will looks like ..../category/sub-category/type/file.xxx --- and then I put whole absolute path to my database

By now I've got triple nested switch, is there any other way how to do it in better way?

Thanks a lot!

There is a pic of HTML code and PHP -- > http://oi59.tinypic.com/352qclx.jpg

Comment: Can only guess from here, but are you setting up category and subcategory in the switch as well, because building up the path doesn't need to know anything about why the values that can be selected are in the drop downs.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure at what point does the switch come in.  However, can't you just do something like following in a single statement?

```
$complete_filepath = "..../$category/$sub_category/$type/$filename";
```

Comment: Cant send a code in here, its too long, sorry guys iam here for the first time.

Comment: you don't need to send the whole code just the related snippet.

Comment: It was too long too. I have added a screenshot, hope it's readable.

Comment: Why don't you put it up on pastie or here: https://gist.github.com/  Image is not really readable.

Comment: I did it in a better way, find better solution, anyway, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

May be a multi-demension array will help you to solve it. like this:

```
$arr_dir_conf = array("dir_conf" =>
    array("category1" => 
        array("sub_category1" =>
            array("type1" => "directory/category1/sub_category1/type1"),
            ...
            array("typen" => "directory/category1/sub_category1/typen")

        ), 
        ...
        array("sub_categoryn" =>
        ...
        ),
    ),
    ...
);
```

Then you just use the array like this:

```
move_uploaded_files($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 
    $arr_dir_conf[$category][$subcategory][$type]);
```